# Not Able to Extract Key for each value in Firebase using React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am not getting the unique key for every values of the table users1

```
firebase.database().ref('users1').once('value').then(snapshot => {
   var items = [];
   snapshot.forEach((child) => {
     items.push({
        keyis: snapshot.val(),
        email: child.val().email,
        password: child.val().password,

       // price: child.val().price,
     });
  });
  this.setState({ users1: items});
  console.log(this.state.users1)
```

I am getting in the form dictionary. I need the unique key for each of the fields and to be stored in keyis variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a `keyis` value to be the string of the key queried snapshot, instead of this:

```
keyis: snapshot.val(),
```

Use the [key](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#key) property of DocumentSnapshot:

```
keyis: snapshot.key,
```

Comment: I am getting the table name with that syntax, I require the unique key for each fields which I have.

Comment: OK, I think you should edit the question to be more specific about what you're trying to do, showing specific examples of input data and expected results.

Comment: ohk will definitely do it, Can u help me out with this if possible.

Comment: Ans to the above question I found out was keyis: firebase.database().ref().push().getKey()